# Excel: conditional formatting from other range

Tags: excel

Is it (easy) possible, to "copy" an conditional formatting from one table to the other? Target is, to get the colors from the left table to the right table (SAME colors!)

Example:
[image]

PS: "Paste Special" "Formats" DONT work, because then the colors in the right table are made of the numbers in the right table. So the colors are NOT the same!

Comment: Only if the formatting is set up with a formula - then you apply the same formual, but with the target cell shifted accordingly. If it's an automatic gradient of some sort, then no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "fixed" the colors with VBA:

```
For Each Zelle In Selection
 Zelle.Interior.Color = Zelle.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
Next Zelle
```